# Android Emulator-x86 not getting started in Android studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have recently downloaded the latest version of Android Studio 2.0 and with this I have got the option of new Emulator i.e. Emulator-x86. But when I am trying to start the emulator it's showing me some error, can anyone please check this?

The error is a pop window and it says:

> The procedure entry point _Z11qt_assert_xPKcS0_S0_i could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library Qt5Core.dll

Comment: what are those "some error" ?

Comment: The error is a pop window and it says:

The procedure entry point _Z11qt_assert_xPKcS0_S0_i could not be located in the dynamic link library Qt5Core.dll @Jabbar_Jigariyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new emulator uses Qt for its UI, and the error you're seeing is about Qt. It feels to me like the issue is that you've got some different Qt version on your path, and it gets loaded into the emulator process instead of the one it needs.

You could try starting the emulator from the hand-crafted command line, with PATH cleaned up from anything what might bring another Qt in.

Answer (score 0):

try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jt3GEgUV2bU if you are getting error then also try to re install the haxm as it may be the cause or try to install the system Image from your sdk.You can test your app using Bluestack or genymotin that will be better and faster.hope it  will help u